# Multiple Ecommerce Transaction because of cached webpage

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I am stuck in a case where Google Analytics is recording multiple eCommerce transaction. We have added code on server side to execute GA eCommerce posting code only one time. Still this issue is reproducible for some transaction. The multiple eCommerce transaction are for same transaction Id but on different dates.

On research I found that this case is with small devices (mobile, tablet). The small devices browser caches whole webpage. And when the browser is opened it reload webpage from cache. So each time user opens the browser and page loads from cache hence the causing this issue.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Ignore double transaction ids" would be quite a useful setting and we should try and make this a feature request. However at the moment it does not exist.

The only way I can think of would be to use an API script that selects the transaction ids for the last "n" days and then inserts a heap of filters via the management API to exclude hits with that transaction id. After some time (when the caches have presumably expired) you could throw out old filters. This would be only feasible if you have a small number of transactions (I think there is an upper limit to the number of filters a view can have).

Or if your transaction ids are somehow sequential (e.g. if they contain the date) you might be able to construct a regex that matches earlier parts of the sequence (e.g. previous dates) and only let's a transaction pass if it is higher up in the sequence than the last recorded transaction id (or does not let it pass if the date in the transaction id is lower than the current date - remember to update your filter at midnight).

Caveat: I have not actually tried something like this, but it sounds like it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We made it possible by refreshing the page after a couple of seconds. Before refresh, the page pushed the transaction details and shows thank you message then reloads to the customer's order receipt page. 

This reduced the duplicate transaction ids cases from 25% to less than 1%.